# How combine & log PCollection correctly after GlobalWindow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running a streaming pipeline that is supposed to ingest a Web-Shop clickstream from PubSub into BigQuery. Beam with Dataflow runner is supposed to help me aggregate the value of purchase events per user. I want to trigger the aggregation per every 10 incoming events.

This should be straightforward, but I am relatively new to beam and seem to be misunderstanding some basic concepts about windowing.

Below the aggregation part of my pipeline.

- 1st, I am filtering for the right event types (working!).
- 2nd, I am applying a global window with repeated trigger.
- 3rd, my composite transform first extracts the right field and assigns a key.
- 4th, my composite transform combines per key and sums.

In this setup I was expecting to receive the grouped sums printed per every 10 items.

Actually nothing is logged, it seems like my `ExtractAndSumValue` transform is not even triggered, since my print statement is not logged.

What am I missing here?

**Pipeline Setup:**

```
fixed_windowed_items = (json_message
                            | 'Filter for purchase' >> beam.Filter(is_purchase)
                            | 'Global Window' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.GlobalWindows(),
                                                                 trigger=trigger.Repeatedly(
                                                                     trigger.AfterCount(10)),
accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING)
                            | 'ExtractAndSumValue' >> ExtractAndSumValue()
                            | 'Print PColl' >> beam.Map(print)
                            )
```

**Composite Transform:**

```
class ExtractAndSumValue(beam.PTransform):
  def __init__(self):
    beam.PTransform.__init__(self)

  def expand(self, pcoll):
    print('expanding!')
    return(
        pcoll
        | beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem['client_id'], elem['ecommerce']['purchase']['value']))
        | beam.CombinePerKey(sum))
```

If I apply `beam.ParDo(print)` right after the global window I see the full json messages in the logs as expected in batches of 10.

Comment: Are you in stream mode?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere
Yes, 'streaming=True' is defined in pipeline options. Also some other pipeline branches stream successfully into BQ without windowing and only item-wise transforms.

Comment: I fear that the global window wait for the end of the stream to continue. However, you trigger config is correct. Not sure what's happen, it's strange that it does not work!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I was thinking the same, but the print statement works fine without the combine. So I figured the problem must be there.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with something similar just today regarding `GroupByKey` and I believe it applies to `CombinePerKey` as well.

According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing-bounded-collections) (however, not at the 'correct' position, i.e. the GroupByKey section)

> We then set a windowing function for that PCollection. The GroupByKey
> transform groups the elements of the PCollection **by both key and**
> **window**, based on the windowing function.

The `trigger.AfterCount(..)` is misleading. It does not mean that every 10 input elements, something is happening in your `CombinePerKey`. Instead, Beam groups/combines your PCollection according to both the key **and** window. In your case, this means it waits until it gets 10 messages for each `client_id`, before summing it up. Apparently, your input data does not contain enough messages belonging to one single client.

I've tested this with `GroupByKey`, where I published 9 messages belonging to the same key to PubSub. The print was never executed. However, once I published message number 10, it immediately printed out the expected result.

To make a long story short, you would need to add additional [triggers](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#triggers), such as event/processing time. Alternatively, you could set `trigger.AfterCount(1)`, but then your `CombinePerKey` would not make sense anymore.